# NSURLConnection Getting Off Main Thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous

Intro:
I have basically learned Obj-C and Cocoa Touch from Stackoverflow over the last few weeks, so bravo community, bravo.

Alas I have come to a question I cannot find an answer to/don't know how to Google.

I am making an app that 100% interfaces with an API service. Here's the process:

1. App launch -> Retrieve token
2. Subsequent requests -> HTTP Header token

My first view controller is a loading icon while a synchronous request takes place.

I would like to make Async requests in the future as currently my UI gets blocked while these requests take place.

My PHP background has caused me to set up my files like this, so let me know if this is incorrect.

- APIConnect.h/.m -> Holds all my API methods
  `-(NSDictionary *)APIcall:(NSString *)api postData:(NSDictionary *)postData`
- TableViewController.h/.m -> Table based off data loaded from the method above.

When selecting a row, it moves forward in the UI and retrieves the details of that item (another API call).

When moving forward, it's apparent the main thread is blocked.

I therefore have tried to set up an async method
`-(NSDictionary *)asyncAPIcall:(NSString *)api postData:(NSDictionary *)postData`

APIConnect.m (abbreviated):

```
-(NSDictionary *)asyncAPIcall:(NSString *)api postData:(NSDictionary *)postData
{
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:queue
                       completionHandler:
 ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
     if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
         [self returnedData:data];
     else
         [self downloadError:error];

 }];
}


-(void)returnedData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSMutableDictionary *returnData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [returnData setDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                          options:0
                                                            error:nil]];

    NSLog(@"Returned Data %@", returnData);
    [self setReturnURLData:returnData];
}
```

I really don't know how to ask my question, so maybe you can help me with that... However in theory I would like to:

- Make an async request within APIConnect.m
- Once async is done, it returns data to TableViewController.m
- Once TableViewController receives data it will run it's processing and run `[self.tableView reloadData];`
- All meanwhile, an activity indicator or something is visible to show that it's working on getting something

Any guidance on what to Google would be super helpful.

Comment: I see a couple of things wrong. You can't return a dictionary from your asyncAPIcall:postData: method because of the async nature of the method -- the method will go out of scope as soon as you send the request, but before the response comes back. One way to handle this situation is to use delegation. Write a delegate protocol in your APIConnect class, and call the delegate method in the async method's completion block to send the data to the table view controller (which would have to set itself as the delegate).

Comment: @rdelmar - Delegate is what I was looking for! In PHP we have Subclasses, and I just knew that couldn't help at all here. Would implementing this affect my UI at all? I had a command that on return data `UITabBarController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Circa99HomeScreenViewController"];[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];` = this now takes 15 seconds + to transition to the new view...

Comment: @rdelmar - got it figured out...the async queue I was using was [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] ... switching to [NSOperationQueue currentQueue] resolved the issue. Let me know if you can think of any push back to not use the current queue, but thanks for helping me solve my question!

Comment: The completion block is supposed to be called on the main queue, so I always use mainQueue to be safe -- the currentQueue will most likely be the mainQueue but it might not be.